# Channel not in Stasis application in asterisk ARI

Tags: php, asterisk, freepbx

I am working with asterisk ARI.My asterisk version is 12.5.0.I have created channels via asterisk ARI.But when i am trying to call it is not display in GUI.I am using zoiper softphone.It showing like below :

**409 - Channel not in a Stasis application**

My php file code is:

```
public function get_channel($id='',$variable=''){
   $url=$this->URL."/channels";
   if($id!=''){
        $url.="/".$id;
   }
   if($variable!=''){
        $url.="/variable?variable=".$variable;
   }
   $result=$this->API->get_ari_data($url);
   return json_decode($result,true);
}
```

This is my extension.conf file code :

```
exten => _X., 1, Set(CHANNEL(language)=en)
exten => _X., n, Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=default)
exten => _X., n, Ringing
exten => _X., n, Wait(1)
exten => _X., n, Answer
exten => _X., n, Ringing
exten => _X., n, Wait(1)
exten => _X.,n,Playback(beep)
exten=>_X.,n,ConfBridge(${EXTEN},default_bridge,default_user,sample_user_menu)
exten => _X., n, Hangup
```

Any idea or any suggestion?

Comment: 12.* is short term support version. Do any new develop for 13.*

Answer (score 0):

For use ARI  your extensions.conf file should be

```
exten => _X., 1,Stasis()
```

That way you say you not use dialplan, but use ARI instead. After that you can launch apps via ARI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But when i add this type of extension that time my conference call is not working.Do you have any examples or tutorials links?

Comment: You have run conference from ARI. Sorry, tutorials can be found by google. It is not SO part.